# django form different values from

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to generate form using existing model. It mostly works however the values that I'm getting via get into my url are showing my Providers **id** and the form displays Provider **name**. How can I keep displaying **name** in the form but getting Provider **slug** instead of **id** as a value from that form?

model

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', always_update='True')
    ...
```

form

```
class FiltersAndSortingForm(forms.Form): 
    provider = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Provider.objects.all().order_by('name'), label='Provider', required=False,)
```

view

```
def resources(request):
    if request.GET:
        provider = request.GET.getlist('provider', '')  

        qset_provider = Q() 
        for x in provider:
            qset_provider |= Q(provider=x) 

        resources = Resource.objects.filter(inactive=0).filter(qset_provider)
        form = FiltersAndSortingForm()
    else:
        form = FiltersAndSortingForm()
        resources = Resource.objects.filter(inactive=0)

    context = {
                    'resources': resources,
                    'form': form,

                    }
    return render(request, 'mainapp/resources.html', context)
```

resources.html

```
         {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field.label }}
                    {{ field }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using Django 1.6. If so you can do the following according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class ProviderModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.slug
```

Then you need to use the `ProviderModelChoiceField` in your form.

Otherwise if you're using 1.7, you can use the argument `to_field_name`. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name).

Comment: I'm using 1.6. So when I use `class ProviderModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField): 
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.slug` and `provider = ProviderModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Provider.objects.all())` my html form will display **slug** but the value passed in the form to the url is still **id**. how can I reverse that ?

Comment: ah ok, got it now. needed to add `to_field_name='slug'` and now I'm getting what I needed. thanks !